# Cannot reject suggested edits with a custom reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

When reviewing suggested edits through the beta review system, I cannot (no longer) reject anything with a custom reason. Rejecting with any of the other options works as usual, but when I select "Custom" I get the following message:

> You seem to be using JavaScript to avoid clicking a radio button, are you sure that is what you want to do?

Comment: This must be an extension or plugin on your end. No repro on Chrome 21 beta.

Comment: @Purmou I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.82 on Mac OS 10.6.8, no plugins whatsoever - until today, it was working fine.

Comment: Hm, interesting...is this still happening? Try to reject one again.

Comment: Yupp, still the same, even after clearing the cache etc.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-reproduced] for me just now with Chrome 21.0.1180.81 (stable). I do have a few extensions but none that trigger on the `/review-beta/suggested-edits` pages.

Comment: This happened to me personally when trying to enter a custom reason also. I cleared the error and tried a canned reason and it worked fine.

Comment: reproduced on Firefox 14.0.1 (ubuntu 12.04). Only plugin installed that might influence javascript is adblock.

Comment: [Reproduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144944/trying-to-reject-a-suggested-edit-with-a-custom-reason-throws-incorrect-error-ab) in Safari 6.0 for OS X Mountain Lion (build 8536.25) and Chrome 23.0.1245.0.

Comment: same on [su] http://i.imgur.com/jLY1M.png

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox 14.0.1 in safe mode. So it doesn't seem to be caused by an add-on...

Comment: Same issue using Chrome 21.0.1180.82 on OS X 10.8

Comment: Reproduced (on SuperUser) with IE9 and Firefox 13 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reproducible every time on OS X 10.8 and Safari 6.0 / Chrome 21.0.1180.82 - no extensions other than 1Password on either.

Comment: On SF too http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3564/cant-reject-an-edit

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome Version 21.0.1180.79 OS X 10.7.3

Comment: Ok everyone, I think we've confirmed that this is a global issue that affects *a lot* of different people. Now, why hasn't it been fixed yet!?

Comment: @animuson: Because it is a weekend and the SO team are still enjoying themselves doing something else.

Comment: Confirmed repro on Mac OS X 10.7.4 with Firefox 14.0.1 (laden with extensions, but no problem on SO until very recently).  My question about this got closed as duplicate (and it was, though my subject was the error message, not what I was trying to do when I got it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fixed now. Sorry about that.

As part of a refactoring related to the new review UI, we started storing "rejection reason ids" with bytes instead of ints, and I failed to notice that we were representing "custom reason" with `-1` on the client side (and [bytes can't be negative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6354134/2749)).

Comment: Well, at least it never gets boring for you! :-)