# Unable to reject an edit without an error

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot reject suggested edits with a custom reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144884/cannot-reject-suggested-edits-with-a-custom-reason)

For some reason I am receiving the attached error when I give a comment to custom reject an edit.

[image]

I don't have a JavaScript script installed that does this. I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.83.

If I click the notification it goes away, but the action has not been carried out.

Comment: That seems to be a similar problem as reported earlier today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144884/cannot-reject-suggested-edits-with-a-custom-reason

Comment: that's an oddly specific error, wonder why that was put together

Comment: @BenBrocka: A while ago there was a hole where it let you reject things without actually providing a reason by either using JavaScript to enable the button or manually enabling the button via an inspector. It didn't get checked server-side and allowed the rejection through without a reason. I believe that's where the error originated.