# Trying to reject a suggested edit with a custom reason throws incorrect error about circumventing radio options

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot reject suggested edits with a custom reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144884/cannot-reject-suggested-edits-with-a-custom-reason)

There were two suggested edits in the queue on Arqade for a tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt:

- [Suggestion 8024](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8024)
- [Suggestion 8025](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8025)

The target tag was incorrect, so I wanted to reject the edit suggestions indicating that they should be suggested for the correct tag:

> hatchi-android is the wrong tag; suggest for hatchi instead.

However, when I went to click the "reject" button after typing in my custom message, I got the following error:

> You seem to be using JavaScript to avoid clicking a radio button. Are you sure that is what you want to do?
>   <sup>([screenshot proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpFwd.png))</sup>

Never mind that the error asked a rhetorical question, it's incorrect. I tried to reject the suggestions in Safari 6.0 for OS X Mountain Lion (build 8536.25) before attempting to reject in Chrome 23.0.1245.0 and getting the same result.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3564/cant-reject-an-edit